# Using object_manipulator on a non-PR2 robot

Tags: ros, object-manipulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the [object_manipulator](http://www.ros.org/wiki/object_manipulator) node on a non-PR2 robot, but it crashes when loading the `PR2ArmKinematicsPlugin`, which is unsurprising because I don't have a PR2 arm. [This changeset](https://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/changeset/53923) suggests that one can exchange the `PR2ArmKinematicsPlugin` for a generic one, but I can't figure out how exactly. There doesn't seem to be a parameter to specify a different IK plugin.

It would be great if I could either

- completely disable using the IK inside `object_manipulator`,
- or even better, configure `object_manipulator` to use the [arm_kinematics_constraint_aware](http://ros.org/wiki/arm_kinematics_constraint_aware) plugin

At the moment, both options don't work because `object_manipulator` crashes on startup. Any hints?

**Update:**

Here's the complete backtrace. Summary: `object_manipulator` loads the `PR2ArmKinematicsPlugin`, which crashes because it expects a PR2 URDF and finds a Katana URDF. My URDF is fine, but I don't have some things like soft joint limits that the PR2 plugin expects to find.

```
gdb --args /home/martin/ros-fuerte/object_manipulator/bin/object_manipulator_node /GraspPlanning:=/openrave_grasp_planner arm/constraint_aware_ik:=/kurtana_arm_kinematics/get_constraint_aware_ik arm/get_fk:=/kurtana_arm_kinematics/get_fk arm/get_ik_solver_info:=/kurtana_arm_kinematics/get_ik_solver_info arm/interpolated_ik:=/interpolated_ik_motion_plan arm/interpolated_ik_set_params:=/interpolated_ik_motion_plan_set_params arm/get_state_validity:=/environment_server/get_state_validity arm/move_arm:=/move_arm arm/joint_trajectory:=/katana_arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action arm/hand_posture_execution:=/gripper_grasp_posture_controller arm/grasp_status:=/gripper_grasp_status __name:=object_manipulator

object_manipulator_node: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = urdf::Joint]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff5e853a5 in __GI_raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
64  ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden.
    in ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff5e853a5 in __GI_raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00007ffff5e88b0b in __GI_abort () at abort.c:92
#2  0x00007ffff5e7dd4d in __GI___assert_fail (assertion=0x7fffe431bc6b "px != 0", file=<optimized out>, line=418, function=<optimized out>) at assert.c:81
#3  0x00007fffe42fb92f in operator-> (this=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418
#4  operator-> (this=<optimized out>) at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-pr2-kinematics-0.4.4/debian/ros-fuerte-pr2-kinematics/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_kinematics/pr2_arm_kinematics/src/pr2_arm_ik.cpp:52
#5  pr2_arm_kinematics::PR2ArmIK::init (this=<optimized out>, robot_model=..., root_name="katana_base_link", tip_name="katana_motor5_wrist_roll_link")
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-pr2-kinematics-0.4.4/debian/ros-fuerte-pr2-kinematics/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_kinematics/pr2_arm_kinematics/src/pr2_arm_ik.cpp:62
#6  0x00007fffe4303c2c in pr2_arm_kinematics::PR2ArmIKSolver::PR2ArmIKSolver (this=<optimized out>, robot_model=..., root_frame_name="katana_base_link", tip_frame_name="katana_motor5_wrist_roll_link", 
    search_discretization_angle=<optimized out>, free_angle=@0x7fffe01d4d6c)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-pr2-kinematics-0.4.4/debian/ros-fuerte-pr2-kinematics/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_kinematics/pr2_arm_kinematics/src/pr2_arm_ik_solver.cpp:47
#7  0x00007fffe4316c6a in pr2_arm_kinematics::PR2ArmKinematicsPlugin::initialize (this=0x7fffe01d4d40, group_name="arm", base_name=<optimized out>, tip_name=<optimized out>, 
    search_discretization=<optimized out>)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-pr2-kinematics-0.4.4/debian/ros-fuerte-pr2-kinematics/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/pr2_kinematics/pr2_arm_kinematics/src/pr2_arm_kinematics_plugin.cpp:89
#8  0x00007ffff0cfa224 in arm_kinematics_constraint_aware::ArmKinematicsSolverConstraintAware::ArmKinematicsSolverConstraintAware (this=0x7fffe01ce870, solver=<optimized out>, cm=0x7ffff69cf7c0, group_name=
    "arm") at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-arm-navigation-1.1.11/debian/ros-fuerte-arm-navigation/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation/arm_kinematics_constraint_aware/src/arm_kinematics_solver_constraint_aware.cpp:71
#9  0x00007ffff3b65e02 in object_manipulator::GraspTesterFast::GraspTesterFast (this=0x7fffe00082a0, cm=<optimized out>, plugin_name="pr2_arm_kinematics/PR2ArmKinematicsPlugin")
    at /home/martin/ros-fuerte/object_manipulator/src/grasp_execution/grasp_tester_fast.cpp:172
#10 0x00007ffff6759720 in object_manipulator::ObjectManipulator::ObjectManipulator (this=0x7fffffffcff8) at /home/martin/ros-fuerte/object_manipulator/src/object_manipulator.cpp:103
#11 0x000000000044db42 in object_manipulator::ObjectManipulatorNode::ObjectManipulatorNode (this=0x7fffffffcf70) at /home/martin/ros-fuerte/object_manipulator/nodes/object_manipulator_node.cpp:85
#12 0x000000000042c20e in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd8d8) at /home/martin/ros-fuerte/object_manipulator/nodes/object_manipulator_node.cpp:97
```

**Update 2:**

The following patch works, but it's not nice. It would be much better to have the plugin configurable using a parameter.

```
diff --git a/include/object_manipulator/grasp_execution/grasp_tester_fast.h b/include/object_manipulator/grasp_execution/grasp_tester_fast.h
index 6f76a25..eb7f059 100644
--- a/include/object_manipulator/grasp_execution/grasp_tester_fast.h
+++ b/include/object_manipulator/grasp_execution/grasp_tester_fast.h
@@ -115,7 +115,7 @@ protected:
 
   //! Also adds a grasp marker at the pre-grasp location
   GraspTesterFast(planning_environment::CollisionModels* cm = NULL,
-         const std::string& plugin_name="pr2_arm_kinematics/PR2ArmKinematicsPlugin");
+         const std::string& plugin_name="arm_kinematics_constraint_aware/KDLArmKinematicsPlugin");
 
   ~GraspTesterFast();
 
diff --git a/include/object_manipulator/place_execution/place_tester_fast.h b/include/object_manipulator/place_execution/place_tester_fast.h
index 3840824..891dc87 100644
--- a/include/object_manipulator/place_execution/place_tester_fast.h
+++ b/include/object_manipulator/place_execution/place_tester_fast.h
@@ -95,7 +95,7 @@ protected:
  public:
   //! Also adds a grasp marker at the pre-grasp location
   PlaceTesterFast(planning_environment::CollisionModels* cm = NULL,
-         const std::string& plugin_name="pr2_arm_kinematics/PR2ArmKinematicsPlugin");
+         const std::string& plugin_name="arm_kinematics_constraint_aware/KDLArmKinematicsPlugin");
 
   ~PlaceTesterFast();
 
diff --git a/include/object_manipulator/tools/ik_tester_fast.h b/include/object_manipulator/tools/ik_tester_fast.h
index 6f900ae..a2e63d4 100644
--- a/include/object_manipulator/tools/ik_tester_fast.h
+++ b/include/object_manipulator/tools/ik_tester_fast.h
@@ -73,7 +73,7 @@ protected:
   pluginlib::ClassLoader<kinematics::KinematicsBase> kinematics_loader_;
 
   IKTesterFast(planning_environment::CollisionModels* cm = NULL,
-         const std::string& plugin_name="pr2_arm_kinematics/PR2ArmKinematicsPlugin");
+         const std::string& plugin_name="arm_kinematics_constraint_aware/KDLArmKinematicsPlugin");
 
   ~IKTesterFast();
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48427/using-object_manipulator-on-a-non-pr2-robot/) by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11816 on 2012-11-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're using the object manipulation stack with our robots. If you want to have a look at how we did that it is available on [Launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/sr-manipulation) (still in development so it's quite hard to install it etc...).

Regarding changing the IK for object manipulator, you should have a look at the file [manipulator.launch](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eshadowrobot/sr-manipulation/trunk/view/head:/sr_object_manipulation_launch/launch/manipulator.launch). The **object_manipulator** node is commented out as we're not using it anymore (we replaced it by a simpler node in **sr_pick_and_place**), but the syntax for calling the IK for our arm is there (all the remaps). The IK solver was generated using the [arm_navigation wizard](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials).

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2012-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-11-19**:
Thanks for your help, Ugo! Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem, though. The `object_manipulator` node has changed since you last used it, so your commented-out stuff won't work any more (mine looks pretty similar).

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2012-11-19**:
Ho OK my bad. May be you should look at sr_pick_and_place in the stack I linked in my answer? You could use it as a base to replace the object_manipulator.